# How can I create a Pandas Dataframe column from another Pandas Timeseries?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with Datetime columns:

```
Parcela     DS1        DC1         DS0        DC0
P1      2016-04-26  2016-09-26  2016-04-11  2016-09-11
P2      2016-04-26  2016-09-26  2016-04-11  2016-09-11
```

I've tried to create a new column with the following code:

```
df['sem'] = prec[df['DS0'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m%d'):df['DS1'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')].sum()
```

where `prec` is another dataframe with a datetime index,

```
 Datetime               prec
 2016-04-13 00:00:00    0.0
 2016-04-13 00:10:00    0.0
```

but I get the following error

```
Cannot convert input of type <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'> to Timestamp
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You may check with

```
df['sem'] = [prec.loc[x:y,'prec'].sum() for x , y in zip(df['DS0'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m%d'),df['DS1'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]
```

Comment: What should I do to avoid the following warning
`A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead`

Comment: @Hugo`[prec.loc[x:y,'prec'].sum() for x , y in zip(df['DS0'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m%d'),df['DS1'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))]`